# How to display items in RecyclerView on fragment with data from Firestore using firestoreui

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem with making a Firestoreui show data from Firestore in RecycleView in a fragment. The app is supposed to show images in a RecycleView after I clicked on an ImageView to change from one RecycleView fragment to another RecycleView fragment but it does not show anything.

I know there are plenty of questions like this but I don't seem to find the correct solution to this problem.

Here's my fragment code

```
class PhotoGalleryFragment : Fragment() {
private var db: FirebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
lateinit var binding: FragmentPhotoGalleryBinding
lateinit var adapter: GalleryAdapter


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false
    )

    //set-up recyclerview
    setUpRecycler()

    return binding.root
}

private fun setUpRecycler() {

    val query = db.collection("photos")

    val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Photos>()
        .setQuery(query, Photos::class.java)
        .build()

    adapter = GalleryAdapter(options)
    binding.galleryRecyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    binding.galleryRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity, 2)
    binding.galleryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    adapter.startListening()
}

override fun onStop() { 
    super.onStop()
    adapter.stopListening()
}

}
}
```

Here's my adapter class

```
class GalleryAdapter(options: FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Photos>) :
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Photos, GalleryAdapter.GalleryViewHolder>(options) {


class GalleryViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var photo: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_image)
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GalleryViewHolder {

    val itemView =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_gallery, parent, false)
    return GalleryViewHolder(itemView)
}


/**
 * @param model the model object containing the data that should be used to populate the view.
 * @see .onBindViewHolder
 */
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GalleryViewHolder, position: Int, model: Photos) {

    Glide.with(holder.photo.context)
        .load(model.imageUrl)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
        .error(R.drawable.ic_star)
        .into(holder.photo)

    //set up navigation
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { view: View ->
        view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_photoGalleryFragment_to_photoFragment)
    }

}
}
```

Here's my model class

```
class Photos {
var imageUrl: String? = null

constructor(imageUrl: String?) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl
}

constructor() {}
}
```

This the data structure  from firestore
[image: firestore data model]

Comment: This app uses single activity multiple fragments

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also add the content of your `Photos` class.

Comment: The Photos class is the model class.

Comment: The data structure is one collection called photos with images as documents which have Fields of imageUrl and value which is a URL of the image saved in cloud storage

Comment: Instead of describing how your database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Please also add the content of your `Photos` class.

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: Dores your `model.imageUrl` contain the right data?

Comment: please how do I check that?

Comment: Log the value `Log.d("TAG", model.imageUrl);`. Is there something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: i got "Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used"

Comment: @bigwig You also need to add tag manager as a depencency in your code, you can follow [this instructions](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/#add-gtm-to-project), if you do that, you will be able to log the value of `model.imageUrl`